# How to predefine variable in function by using different variable?

Tags: php

I dont know how to predefine one of the variables in function.

```
<?php 
    $number = 3;
    function test($num, $num2 = $number) {
        $result = "num = ".$num." and num2 = ".$num2;
        return $result;
    }


    echo test(1);

?>
```

It always prints out:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use it like this:

```
function test($num, $num2 = 3) {/**/}
```

But, if you really need it, you can define a constant:

```
const NUMBER = 3;

function test($num, $num2 = NUMBER)
{
    $result = "num = $num and num2 = $num2";
    return $result;
}

echo test(1); // returns "num = 1 and num2 = 3"
```

And the 3d option, if you want to use some dynamic variable:

```
$number = 3;

function test($num, $num2)
{
    $result = "num = $num and num2 = $num2";
    return $result;
}

echo test(1, $number); // returns "num = 1 and num2 = 3"
```

Or you can use a class:

```
class Test
{
    protected $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function test($num)
    {
        $result = "num = $num and num2 = $this->number";
        return $result;
    }
}

$test = new Test(3);

echo $test->test(1); // returns "num = 1 and num2 = 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want assingn   a default value to a param you must use a value (a constant expression)  not a var (variable expression)

```
function test($num, $num2 = 3 )
```

Comment: ok, but I would like to use var or something like that. Is it possible?

Comment: why ??   .. when you need  yo can pass the var content. in function call  `test($num, $number)  ..   So way you want assign the default param value as a variable expression instead a constant expression ..